# c# Incorrect XML to deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, deserialization

I have this XML, and i need deserialize but type is incorrect.

```
<Consumer>
  <Sex type="int">Man</Sex>
</Consumer>
```

How could i fix out? I like to allow int and string.

Thx in advance,

Comment: Please provide your XML and code

Comment: If Consumer is a C# class -- are you parsing Man to an enum? If not, you might have trouble parsing it to an int.

Comment: What created this xml because it sure wasn't seralized using .NET and if it was there is a problem with the code.

Comment: the problem is xml is incorrect, but i want not to throw exception

Comment: try..catch....? that will allow you to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you are going to accomplish this is by manually parsing the XML.

All of the regular tools are going to throw a fit over the fact that "Man" is by no means an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Please doing folowing action. 
Load your XML into Visual Studio, click the "Infer Schema" button, and run "xsd.exe /c schema.xsd" to generate the classes. xsd.exe is in the tools folder. Then go through the generated code and make adjustments, such as changing shorts to ints where appropriate.

check [this link](http://www.codingday.com/xml-c-class-generator-for-c-using-xsd-for-deserialization/)